# Use VBA code for enabling checkboxes on multiple rows

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxI6E.png)I have a spreadsheet that has 3 checkbox options for each row, I have created a VBA to disable the other 2 checkboxes once a checkbox is created (so that only 1 checkbox can be checked), however my solution only works for one row and I need some help in rewriting this so that it will apply to all rows please. (I'm new to VBA).

The code I have used is this:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
  CheckBox2.Value = False
  CheckBox2.Enabled = False
  CheckBox3.Value = False
  CheckBox3.Enabled = False
Else
  CheckBox2.Value = False
  CheckBox2.Enabled = True
  CheckBox3.Value = False
  CheckBox3.Enabled = True
End If
End Sub
Private Sub CheckBox2_Click()
If CheckBox2.Value = True Then
  CheckBox1.Value = False
  CheckBox1.Enabled = False
  CheckBox3.Value = False
  CheckBox3.Enabled = False
Else
  CheckBox1.Value = False
  CheckBox1.Enabled = True
  CheckBox3.Value = False
  CheckBox3.Enabled = True
End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox3_Click()
If CheckBox3.Value = True Then
  CheckBox1.Value = False
  CheckBox1.Enabled = False
  CheckBox2.Value = False
  CheckBox2.Enabled = False
Else
  CheckBox1.Value = False
  CheckBox1.Enabled = True
  CheckBox2.Value = False
  CheckBox2.Enabled = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please edit your question and place a picture with your sheet keeping the check boxes. When you say "3 checkbox options for each row", do you mean an Excel row? If yes, are there other rows without such check boxes on them? The, are they Form or ActiveX type?

Comment: Thank you very much for the responses. It won't let me upload an image as I'm new, but the checkboxes have been created with ActiveX controls. There are 3 columns alongside each other on the spreadsheet, each with a checkbox (so 3 checkboxes on a row) which offer different options and I need only 1 of those options to be selected per row.

Comment: Then, try my code solution, please. It works for ActiveX check boxes, too. But you must add a piece of code in their `Click` event code, as shown...

Comment: I will now add a sub able to automatically create click events for all involved ActiveX check boxes. Did you try testing the proposed solution? It is not so complicate like it looks at the first sight...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably just use Radios it would be a lot simpler.

If you are intent on doing this you will need to delete all your boxes and then put this code in. It will create and name your boxes and assign them code on click.

Alright, This needs to go in your Sheet module:

```
Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    'Change Module2 to whatever the module name you are using is.
    Module2.ActivateCheckBoxes ActiveSheet
End Sub
```

This next stuff will go into the module you're referencing from the Worksheet Module.

```
Sub ActivateCheckBoxes(sht As Worksheet)
    If sht.CheckBoxes.Count = 0 Then
        CreateCheckBoxes sht
    End If
    Dim cb As CheckBox
    
    For Each cb In sht.CheckBoxes
        'You may be able to pass sht as an object, It was giving me grief though
        cb.OnAction = "'Module2.CheckBoxClick """ & cb.name & """, """ & sht.name & """'"
    Next cb
End Sub

Sub CreateCheckBoxes(sht As Worksheet)
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim chkbox As CheckBox
    With sht
        Dim i As Long
        Dim prevrow As Long
        prevrow = 0
        For Each cell In .Range("B2:D5") 'Change this to whatever range you want.
            If prevrow < cell.row Then
                prevrow = cell.row
                i = 0
            End If
            Set chkbox = .CheckBoxes.Add(cell.Left, cell.Top, 30, 6)
            With chkbox
                .name = "CheckBox" & i & "_" & cell.row
                .Caption = ""
            End With
            
            i = i + 1
        Next cell
    End With                             
End Sub

Sub CheckBoxClick(chkname As String, sht As String)
    Dim cb As CheckBox
    With Worksheets(sht)

        For Each cb In .CheckBoxes
            If Split(cb.name, "_")(1) Like Split(chkname, "_")(1) And Not cb.name Like chkname Then
                cb.Value = -4146
            End If
        Next cb
    End With
            
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You do not say anything about your sheet check boxes type... Please, test the next solution. It will be able to deal with both sheet check boxes type:

1. Copy this two `Subs` in a standard module:

```
Public Sub CheckUnCheckRow(Optional strName As String)
  Dim sh As Worksheet, s As CheckBox, chK As OLEObject ' MSForms.CheckBox
   Set sh = ActiveSheet
  If strName <> "" Then
    Set chK = sh.OLEObjects(strName) '.OLEFormat.Object
    solveCheckRow chK.Object.Value, sh, Nothing, chK
  Else
    Set s = sh.CheckBoxes(Application.Caller)
    solveCheckRow s.Value, sh, s
  End If
End Sub
Sub solveCheckRow(boolVal As Long, sh As Worksheet, chF As CheckBox, Optional chK As OLEObject)
 Dim s As CheckBox, oObj As OLEObject, iCount As Long
 
    If Not chF Is Nothing Then
        For Each s In sh.CheckBoxes
            If chF.TopLeftCell.Address <> s.TopLeftCell.Address Then
                If s.TopLeftCell.Row = chF.TopLeftCell.Row Then
                    s.Value = IIf(boolVal = -4146, 1, -4146): iCount = iCount + 1
                    If iCount = 2 Then Exit Sub
                End If
            End If
        Next
    ElseIf Not chK Is Nothing Then
        For Each oObj In sh.OLEObjects
            If oObj.TopLeftCell.Address <> chK.TopLeftCell.Address Then
                If oObj.TopLeftCell.Row = chK.TopLeftCell.Row Then
                  boolStopEvents = True
                    oObj.Object.Value = IIf(boolVal = 0, True, False): iCount = iCount + 1
                  boolStopEvents = False
                    If iCount = 2 Then Exit Sub
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

2. For case of Form check boxes type:

a). Manually assign the first sub **to all your Form Type check boxes** (right click - Assign Macro, choose  `CheckUnCheckRow` and press OK).

b). Automatically assign the macro:

```
  Dim sh As Worksheet, s As CheckBox
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet ' use here your sheet keeping the check boxes
  For Each s In sh.CheckBoxes
        s.OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!CheckUnCheckRow"
  Next
End Sub
```

If your check boxes have already assigned a macro, adapt `CheckUnCheckRow`, in Form check boxes section, to also call that macro...

3. For case of ActiveX check boxes:

a). Create a `Public` variable on top of a standard module (in the declarations area):

```
Public boolStopEvents
```

b). Manually adapt all your ActiveX check boxes `Click` or `Change` event, like in the next example:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
   If Not boolStopEvents Then CheckUnCheckRow "CheckBox1"
End Sub
Private Sub CheckBox2_Click()
   If Not boolStopEvents Then CheckUnCheckRow "CheckBox2"
End Sub
Private Sub CheckBox3_Click()
   If Not boolStopEvents Then CheckUnCheckRow "CheckBox3"
End Sub
```

and so on...

c). Or do all that with a click, using the next piece of code:

```
Sub createEventsAllActiveXCB()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, oObj As OLEObject, strCode As String, ButName As String
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here your sheet keeping ActveX check boxes
   For Each oObj In sh.OLEObjects
        If TypeName(oObj.Object) = "CheckBox" Then
            ButName = oObj.Name
            strCode = "Private Sub " & ButName & "_Click()" & vbCrLf & _
                      "     If Not boolStopEvents Then CheckUnCheckRow """ & ButName & """" & vbCrLf & _
                      "End Sub"
            addClickEventsActiveXChkB sh, strCode
        End If
   Next
End Sub
```

Anyhow, the code cam be simplified in order to deal with only a type of such check boxes. If you intend to use it and looks too bushy, I can adapt it only for the type you like. Like it is, the code deals with both check box types, if both exist on the sheet...

Save the workbook and start playing with the check boxes. But, when you talk about check boxes on a row, **all tree of them** must have the same `TopLeftCell.Row`...